# RegExr.com Substitution With New Line Feed

Tags: regex, newline

I'm using [RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/) for some regex match and substitution.  The website is pretty easy to use, and it's good in general.

However, I don't know how to replace a match with the new line feed. When I put `\n`, it gives me the literal '\n', instead of a real new line feed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure? If I put the `\n` in the Substitution, it gives me the literal `\n`. Are you putting `\n` in Expression or Substitution? I'm asking the Substitution. Expression is also working for me.

Comment: I see. That is annoying. You could just put `\n` and then use any editor to find and replace all literal `\n` with newlines.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing (Using Word or other text editors) for now, but it's very annoying, RegExr.com is still a very nice tool though.

Comment: @PeterLee You will like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Yeah your out of luck there, I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/gskinner/regexr/issues/11) for you, Hopefully somebody in the know will fix it for you! Shameless plug for sublimetext, it has awesome regex find and find replace!

Comment: Usually the replacement side is interpolated, or should be. I'm of the belief that testing should be run on the environment the expression is to be used, its permanent home, not Motel 6.

Answer (score 0):

The author notes:

> Right, we currently limit the Expression and Substitution fields to single line input. I've considered treating the Substitution value as a Javascript string, so you can use "\n" and other encoded characters. Open to feedback on this.

See also Thor's comment: https://github.com/gskinner/regexr/issues/11